# Symfony multiple instances of an entity in a form submission

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

In Symfony 2.7, I have an entity called Task against which I have persisted 5 entries in the database with the following fields:
ID, TaskName, Date

Now I want to set weights to these entries using a separate entity called Weights (obviously using relationships) the new weights class would have these fields:-
ID, TaskID (Foreign Key), WeightValue

And the rendered form should show all 5 entries of Task type in a twig template and then a text box against each entry to enter weight values like this:-

---

Task1     [txtbox]

---

Task2     [txtbox]

---

....
[SUBMIT]

And when I submit the form all these values should be validated and persisted to the database in Weights table with a related value in TaskID column as a relationship.
What could be the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly does Weight have to be a relationship and not just a new property of task? Please see [Doctrine Best Practices](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#constrain-relationships-as-much-as-possible).

Just create a FormType for Tag containing both the name and weight and persist everything in the Tag-entity as you would normally. [See the cookbook for a good example.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)